# Destroy trail when finished

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a missile with a trail renderer attached to it.

I want to destroy the game object (with the trail) after finishing the rendering process.

The code below does not work:

```
private TrailRenderer tr;


public void Start() {
    tr = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
}

public void Update() {

    if(tr) {

        if(tr.isVisible == false) {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` inside `if(tr.isVisible == false)` and see if that even evaluates to true. If the log is not called then that's the problem. Also put another one inside `if(tr)` to see if the `tr` variable is successfully initialized in the `Start` function.

Comment: I already put Debug.log inside if (tr.isVisible == false) and nothing is showing up. That's the problem. Is there an alternative way to check whether the rendering process has finished?

Comment: How about iniside if(tr)? That condition must be met too. What do you mean by "rendering process has finished"? It would be better to just explain when the TrailRenderer should be destroyed. Your current attempt to explain that is confusing

Comment: Inside if(tr) results in true. That works. With rendering process I mean when the trail animation has just finished. Then I want to destroy the object.

Comment: See ryeMoss's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you wish to destroy the trail renderer when the duration of the final trail segment `time` has elapsed. If that is the case, as Eddge suggested, you should destroy after a delay once your missile is destroyed or stops moving:

```
private TrailRenderer tr;

void Start() {
    tr = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
}

public void MissileDestroyed()
{
    Destroy(gameObject, tr.time);
}
```

Comment: Hm. When I use this code my trail disappears with a delay right after releasing a missile. This does not look good.

Comment: Have you looked into the auto destruct property?

Comment: @drpelz can you show us exactly what you mean?  Like the missile is still there and moving and the trail disappears? (When you say release, I am not sure if you mean when you fire or destroy the missile)

Comment: @Eddge, looking back and I agree - will update answer